# Import SVG in TypeScript React app with Webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, svg, webpack

I'd like to import an SVG image into a little React app written with TypeScript and bundled with Webpack. The problem is that that no image is shown (only the browser's fallback image that no image was found). It seems like the data URL is wrong, because when I copy the data URL in a base64 decoder the image is broken.

I'm tried different Webpack loaders (url-loader, file-loader, svg-loader, ...)

`webpack.config.json`

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.svg$/,
      loader: 'url-loader'
    }
  ]
}
```

`tsd.d.ts`

```
declare module "*.svg" {
  const content:string;
  export default content;
}
```

`App.tsx`

```
import content from './logo.svg';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    <div>
      <img src={content} />
    </div>
  }
}
```

Any ideas what to change?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check if `const content = require('./logo.svg')` works

Comment: I'll check it in the evening and reply as soon as I know it. thanks for your comment

Comment: your suggestion did not work, @niba. same problem as with ES2015 import syntax

Comment: so it looks like it's a problem of webpack loader, you know that react supports svg and you can make a component from that svg?

Comment: Yes, I know that. But I'd like to fix this issue, because I'd like to use this setup in other apps and importing a SVG will be needed again. Not sure if it's a problem of the webpack loader, because I tried two different versions (including the latest)

Comment: could you create a very simple repo that would reproduce your problem? it's very hard to help you without that

Comment: I just wanted to create a small example repo on GitHub and found the problem. I'll answer it below. thanks for your help, @niba!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My problem was that Webpack was misconfigured.

I had, beside others, the following two loader configurations:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.svg$/,
      loader: 'url-loader'
    },
    {
      test   : /\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9=&.]+)?$/,
      loader : 'file-loader'
    }
  ]
}
```

The problem was that I had `svg` in both rules, therefore webpack used the wrong loader. Removing the `svg` part from the second rule solved the issue